# OpenLayers 7: Feature Styles vs Layer Styles

Tags: openlayers

I have a OpenLayer (7.1) Map with around 130 different Icons grouped into 9 groups.
Additionally a user can create LineStrings (with different dashes and user picked colors) and Polygons.

Currently I have 9 Layers for each of the Icons, 4 Layers for labels, a LayerGroup for the LineStrings, where I have Layers for LineStrings, depending on a feature property and a Polygon Layer.

Layers can be turned on/off via `ol-layerswitcher`. Thats the main reason why I'm currently using this Layer structure. Each Layer has a style function and depending on the feature shows the correct Icon/LineString Color.

Now I have user requests to be able to turn off/on specific symbols. So I either create now around 130 Layers or set the style to null on that feature type.

I also read about feature styles and wonder now, if I could just pack all in one Layer and just use feature styles instead or one big layer using null style to hide. Which would help me also a lot as I then have one source and not like now for each layer a different source where I have to haggle around where to put a feature now.

I didn't found any good recommendations when to use Feature styles and when to use Layer styles?

Or maybe a general rule to not use more than xx Layers because of performance?

Does anyone can give me a recommendation if it would be better with just one source and one layer and packing all into feature styles? Or to have a lot of Layers?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a property in each feature, and use that to toggle its visibility in the style function.

```js
// show feature
feature.setProperty("visible", true)
// hide feature
feature.setProperty("visible", false)

function Stylefunction (feature, resolution) {
    var props = feature.getProperties();
    
    if (props.visible) {
      // set opacity to 1
    } else {
      // set opacity to 0
    }
}
```

If you are using the same image for multiple features, I'd recommend having only one icon in reference instead of creating a new icon for every feature. This will improve performance a lot if you have a lot of features.

For example, have multiple features reference this icon:

```js
const sharedStyle = new Style({
    image: new Icon({
        src: mySvg,
    })
})
```